# to correctly target delegate if I don't want to create instance and setting delegate in viewDidLoad() but in some method?

Tags: iphone, xcode, delegates

How to correctly target delegate if I don't want to create instance and setting delegate in viewDidLoad() but in some method? Everything is working, but got warning.

```
// ViewController.m    
// Warning: Assigning to 'id'<UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> from incomplatible type 'ViewController *const __strong

-(void)takeMedia:(UIButton *)sender
{  
  mypicker = [UIImagePickerController new];
  mypicker.delegate = self; // <<<----
  mypicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
  [self presentViewController:mypicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Did you implement the methods required by UIImagePickerControllerDelegate? imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: and imagePickerControllerDidCancel: ?

Comment: yes, I wrote all is working but got Warning and trying to figure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have included both the delegates in your header file like

```
@interface MyViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```